# r How to remove weekday after-hours periods (as well as weekends and holodays) from x-axis when plotting intraday data

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod

In R, I am plotting some intraday price data at 5 min. intervals and so need to modify the x-axis so as to remove time periods when the market is closed, i.e. from 4pm to 9am Mondays-Fridays, excluding holidays.

I have come closest to achieving this using the package bdscale, which was not specifically designed to remove weekday after-hours periods, but sort of does it.

Here is a repoducible example, although it requires an alpha vantage API key (which is free).

```
library(tidyquant)
library(alphavantager)
library(bdscale)
library(scales)

this_ts <- "SPY"
av_api_key("YOUR_KEY_HERE")
df_ohlcv <- this_ts %>%
  tq_get(get = "alphavantager", av_fun = "TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY", interval = "5min")
df_ohlcv$p <- rowSums(df_ohlcv[, c(3:5)]) / 3
df <- df_ohlcv[, c("timestamp", "p")]
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = timestamp, y = p))
gg <- gg + geom_line()
gg <- gg + scale_x_bd(business.dates = df$timestamp, labels = date_format("%a\n%b %d\n%H:%M"))
gg
```

[image: this]

As you can see, the resulting plot removes the after-hours time period, but the x-axis labeling gets messed up. Also, the grey panels in the background are wonky. Perhaps using something besides bdscale would be better? Help appreciated.

EDIT:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1563286500, 1563286800, 
1563287100, 1563287400, 1563287700, 1563288000, 1563288300, 1563288600, 
1563288900, 1563289200, 1563289500, 1563289800, 1563290100, 1563290400, 
1563290700, 1563291000, 1563291300, 1563291600, 1563291900, 1563292200, 
1563292500, 1563292800, 1563356100, 1563356400, 1563356700, 1563357000, 
1563357300, 1563357600, 1563357900, 1563358200, 1563358500, 1563358800, 
1563359100, 1563359400, 1563359700, 1563360000, 1563360300, 1563360600, 
1563360900, 1563361200, 1563361500, 1563361800, 1563362100, 1563362400, 
1563362700, 1563363000, 1563363300, 1563363600, 1563363900, 1563364200, 
1563364500, 1563364800, 1563365100, 1563365400, 1563365700, 1563366000, 
1563366300, 1563366600, 1563366900, 1563367200, 1563367500, 1563367800, 
1563368100, 1563368400, 1563368700, 1563369000, 1563369300, 1563369600, 
1563369900, 1563370200, 1563370500, 1563370800, 1563371100, 1563371400, 
1563371700, 1563372000, 1563372300, 1563372600, 1563372900, 1563373200, 
1563373500, 1563373800, 1563374100, 1563374400, 1563374700, 1563375000, 
1563375300, 1563375600, 1563375900, 1563376200, 1563376500, 1563376800, 
1563377100, 1563377400, 1563377700, 1563378000, 1563378300, 1563378600, 
1563378900, 1563379200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    p = c(299.738333333333, 299.628333333333, 299.616666666667, 
    299.633333333333, 299.556666666667, 299.658333333333, 299.805, 
    299.843333333333, 299.913333333333, 299.843333333333, 299.844, 
    299.935, 299.963333333333, 300.003333333333, 300.016666666667, 
    299.924333333333, 299.92, 299.985, 300.046666666667, 299.958333333333, 
    299.95, 299.846666666667, 299.77, 299.78, 299.753333333333, 
    299.563333333333, 299.626666666667, 299.598333333333, 299.585, 
    299.43, 299.256666666667, 299.1333, 299.13, 299.096666666667, 
    299.046633333333, 299.063333333333, 298.804333333333, 298.59, 
    298.45, 298.598333333333, 298.763333333333, 298.776333333333, 
    298.893333333333, 298.875, 298.915, 298.844966666667, 298.83, 
    298.86, 299.036666666667, 299.129033333333, 299.203333333333, 
    299.136633333333, 299.058333333333, 299.038333333333, 298.873, 
    298.856666666667, 298.8373, 298.846666666667, 298.863333333333, 
    298.938333333333, 298.970033333333, 298.88, 298.912266666667, 
    298.95, 298.903333333333, 298.871666666667, 298.86, 298.8, 
    298.805666666667, 298.843966666667, 298.886533333333, 298.9178, 
    299.028333333333, 299.015, 298.986666666667, 298.973333333333, 
    298.818466666667, 298.708166666667, 298.548333333333, 298.543333333333, 
    298.613333333333, 298.66, 298.716666666667, 298.753333333333, 
    298.7, 298.693333333333, 298.6067, 298.586, 298.388333333333, 
    298.458333333333, 298.613333333333, 298.6254, 298.45, 298.245, 
    298.335, 298.361666666667, 298.273333333333, 298.258333333333, 
    298.266666666667, 298.027566666667)), .Names = c("timestamp", 
"p"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: I suggest doing a facet per day. `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`

Comment: Instead of us needing to register for a key, can you just post a `dput` of a bit of the data that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: What should I execute? `dput(gg)`?

Comment: `dput(df)` please :-)

Comment: @TobiO Done, see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's an easy solution to change the breaks in the way you desire without converting your scale to a discrete one.

The disadvantage of doing this is that you lose the ability to set your breaks flexibly as in `scale_x_datetime`. To get around this I've given some examples of how to set up some handy breaks by altering your dataframe as in the example below. I've also converted the timestamp column into a character for use with the discrete scale.

I've made the assumption that, since you're grabbing data for market hours, that the market hours are already defined by the timestamp column in your data. This saves from defining a custom scale that excludes holidays etc.

```r
# convert to character column and set up handy columns for making breaks
df <- df %>%
      mutate(timestamp_chr = as.character(df$timestamp),
             day = lubridate::day(timestamp),
             hour = lubridate::hour(timestamp),
             minute = lubridate::minute(timestamp),
             new_day = if_else(day != lag(day) | is.na(lag(day)), 1, 0))


df

# # A tibble: 100 x 7
#    timestamp              p    day  hour minute timestamp_chr       new_day
#    <dttm>              <dbl> <int> <int>  <int> <chr>                 <dbl>
# 1  2019-07-16 14:15:00  300.    16    14     15 2019-07-16 14:15:00       1
# 2  2019-07-16 14:20:00  300.    16    14     20 2019-07-16 14:20:00       0
# 3  2019-07-16 14:25:00  300.    16    14     25 2019-07-16 14:25:00       0
# 4  2019-07-16 14:30:00  300.    16    14     30 2019-07-16 14:30:00       0
# 5  2019-07-16 14:35:00  300.    16    14     35 2019-07-16 14:35:00       0
# 6  2019-07-16 14:40:00  300.    16    14     40 2019-07-16 14:40:00       0
# 7  2019-07-16 14:45:00  300.    16    14     45 2019-07-16 14:45:00       0
# 8  2019-07-16 14:50:00  300.    16    14     50 2019-07-16 14:50:00       0
# 9  2019-07-16 14:55:00  300.    16    14     55 2019-07-16 14:55:00       0
# 10 2019-07-16 15:00:00  300.    16    15      0 2019-07-16 15:00:00       0
# # … with 90 more rows


# breaks equally spaced
my_breaks <-df$timestamp_chr[seq.int(1,length(df$timestamp_chr) , by = 10)]


ggplot(df, aes(x = timestamp_chr, y = p, group = 1)) +  
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = my_breaks) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

In the above example I've used equally spaced breaks but you could also specify, for example:

```r
# breaks on the hour
my_breaks <- df[df$minute == 0,]$timestamp_chr


# breaks at start of each new day
my_breaks <- df[df$new_day == 1,]$timestamp_chr
```